# Which is better AMD or Nvidia cards for Linux?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ati

I just got rid of my old graphics card and now I will be buying a new one, but since am new to ubuntu which one do you guys suggest me to get for linux/ubuntu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use open source drivers, AMD is the way to go, but if you game and want max performance, Nvidia is better. AMD's open source drivers are much more developed than Nvidia open source drivers but Nvidia's proprietary drivers beat any of AMD's drivers.

[Here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=steamos-22-gpus&num=2) you can see some benchmarks for more info.

Comment: What about intel gpu drivers vs amd? Which are better in performance (open source only, not proprietary)?

Comment: Well if you are comparing the drivers to their standard windows counterparts, Intel's drivers are equal to the windows drivers (maybe even better in some cases), and AMD's open source drivers are worse than their windows counterparts. However in terms of raw performance,  AMD definitely beats Intel since they produce actual dedicated GPUs rather than integrated iGPUs. Basically Intel's software is better but AMD still out performs due to their better hardware. Also keep in mind that the AMD drivers have been improving with time.